# Long boot time after dual-boot (now removed) with Debian

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, boot-time

Distribution: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Minimal) with i3 as window manager.

Output of `systemd-analyze`:

```
Startup finished in 11.412s (kernel) + 3min 2.797s (userspace) = 3min 14.209s
```

Output of `systemd-analyze critical-analyze`:

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 37.581s
└─multi-user.target @1min 37.573s
  └─getty.target @1min 37.570s
    └─getty@tty1.service @1min 37.567s
      └─rc-local.service @1min 37.436s +9ms
        └─network.target @1min 37.423s
          └─wpa_supplicant.service @1min 38.892s +1.846s
             └─basic.target @1min 32.554s
              └─sockets.target @1min 32.554s
                └─dbus.socket @1min 32.553s
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 32.549s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @13.304s +272ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @12.526s +591ms
                        └─local-fs.target @12.458s
                          └─run-user-1000.mount @1min 50.082s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @4.841s
                               └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @3.032s +1.787s
                                └─kmod-static-nodes.service @2.644s +219ms
                                  └─system.slice @2.454s
                                    └─-.slice @2.438s
```

Output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
      9.328s dev-sda5.device
      4.698s ufw.service
      4.381s NetworkManager.service
      3.395s ModemManager.service
      3.391s accounts-daemon.service
      2.271s systemd-udevd.service
      2.086s systemd-rfkill.service
      1.846s wpa_supplicant.service
      1.787s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.619s keyboard-setup.service
      1.480s networking.service
      1.450s systemd-journald.service
      1.371s grub-common.service
      1.332s console-setup.service
      1.307s lightdm.service
      1.104s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.079s resolvconf.service
      1.023s systemd-logind.service
       982ms avahi-daemon.service
       866ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       848ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       820ms dev-mqueue.mount
       772ms binfmt-support.service
       728ms colord.service
       713ms polkitd.service
       707ms ondemand.service
       705ms plymouth-start.service
       660ms dev-hugepages.mount
       659ms rsyslog.service
       651ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       630ms systemd-sysctl.service
       622ms gdomap.service
       591ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       563ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       524ms systemd-random-seed.service
       509ms sysstat.service
       445ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       436ms pppd-dns.service
       371ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       347ms home.mount
       272ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       244ms plymouth-read-write.service
       231ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
       219ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       208ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       146ms user@1000.service
       126ms systemd-backlight@backlight:eeepc.service
        89ms alsa-restore.service
        71ms setvtrgb.service
        59ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
        54ms rtkit-daemon.service
        52ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        36ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
        33ms ureadahead-stop.service
        15ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         9ms rc-local.service
```

(Probable) Responsible candidates:

1. `sysinit.target @1min 32.549s`
2. `run-user-1000.mount @1min 50.082s`

Questions:

Any ideas as to how to reduce the time of the above candidates?

Also, if I am interpreting it in a wrong way, can anybody please correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the problem.

As the boot time was too long, I wanted to check what was going on behind the scenes. Therefore, I changed the following line in the file `/etc/default/grub` from:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

***to***

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
```

On the next reboot, found out that the boot process got stuck at:

> [*    ] A start job is running at... dev ... disk...

So, after reboot, I opened the `/etc/fstab` file and also ran the command `sudo blkid`. Turns out that during the installation of Debian my swap partition got formatted and thus, its UUID was changed too.

I changed the `UUID` value in `/etc/fstab` to the current value obtained from `sudo blkid` and now my system boots up fine.

Comment: Excellent, this was exactly my issue too. After Debian install it reformatted the swap changing the UUID. It seems there is no option in the installer to just use the partition without formatting it.