# stuck in tty1 because of changes in fstab-file

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 16.04

Recentley i installed another linux distro on another partition on my SSD disk. During the instalation i reinstalled grub on the computer, and ever since my Ubuntu OS has been very slow to boot up. This has never been an issue before , and im very qurious to find out what is causing it.

Before this, the boot has been very fast. As soon as i log in the ssd seems to work fine, no change i behaviour.

I reinstalled grub on my ubuntu distro and now grub displayes Ubuntu and an old linux mint distro i have deleted to make room for a new one.

I followwed another solution changing the UUID in /etc/fstab, by baking up the original and creating a new one.

I ran:

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

This file was empty so I entered the UUID for the swap memory partition. Now I'm stuck in tty1.

I've tried to reinstall Ubuntu desktop, ctrl + alt +f7, tried to run `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart` nothing works. I've checked a lot of similar issues "stuck in tty1" etc. nothing is working.

Trying to fix the /etc/fstab.bak file by running:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab.bak /etc/fstab
```

is not working beacause i only get "read-only" in the tty1 output. Please help, i dont want to reinstall my OS.

Update: 
I tried following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737319/ubuntu-is-booting-very-slowly-after-dual-boot-with-kali), but every terminal command in the answer gives output like: this doesnt exist, no such directory etc.

I've looked at several similar tty1 issues/post and i'm still stuck.

Comment: I had the same problem. Try my [solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/811289/long-boot-time-after-dual-boot-now-removed-with-debian) and see if it works.

Comment: I did the changes to the grub-file, but where do i find the output(process) you refered to in your solution?

Comment: From Ubuntu try 'sudo grub-install /dev/sda'

Comment: well i didnt help the boot up speed, and now i have to enter the BIOS to boot in the other distro. My grub now displayes Ubuntu and an old Linux mint distro i deleted to make room for the new one.

Comment: @Steingrim - Do this: `sudo cp /etc/fstab.bak /etc/fstab` from your tty and then reboot your system, then follow the steps from 4.

Comment: It says cannot create regular file, because of read-only file system

Comment: @Steingrim - From GRUB menu boot into `recovery mode`, then type `sudo blkid` and note the partition number of your Ubuntu partition something like: `/dev/sdaX`. Then run - `mount -t ext4 -o rw,remount /dev/sdaX /`. Now, issue the command: `sudo cp /etc/fstab.bak /etc/fstab`. Now, reboot to Ubuntu and follow from step 4.

Comment: Very much Related : http://askubuntu.com/questions/737319/ubuntu-is-booting-very-slowly-after-dual-boot-with-kali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737319/ubuntu-is-booting-very-slowly-after-dual-boot-with-kali) answer gave me the idea to boot from usb disk image. From there none of the provided terminal codes worked expect mounting the partition i couldnt access.

Then i accessed my partition from:

```
/media
```

found the fstab file and followed the provided answer above.

Answer (score 3):

Well you didn't have to follow the steps from my answer exactly. But here is a detailed way to recover your system from the slow boot:

1. Undo the `GRUB` modification:

   - Open GRUB:

     ```
     sudo nano /etc/default/grub
     ```
   - Change this line:

     ```
     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
     ```

     to

     ```
     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
     ```
   - Now save the file and exit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.
   - Update GRUB:

     ```
     sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
     ```
2. Now, open a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```

   and note down the `UUID` of your swap partition. The output will have a line that looks something like:

   ```
   /dev/sda6: UUID="727cac18-044b-4504-87f1-a5aefa774bda" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="8rof66hg-12"
   ```

---

ITS BETTER TO COPY THE `UUID` PART FROM THE ABOVE OUTPUT, i.e., 727cac18-044b-4504-87f1-a5aefa774bda

---

3. **BACKUP YOUR EXISTING FSTAB FIRST** BY TYPING THE FOLLOWING COMMAND:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
   ```

   - 3a. Next, open your `etc/fstab` file:

     ```
     sudo nano /etc/fstab
     ```
4. Repalce the `UUID` of the existing `swap` partition with the one that you copied earlier, i.e., change

   ```
   UUID=whateverishere none        swap        defaults    0 0
   ```

   to

   ```
   UUID=727cac18-044b-4504-87f1-a5aefa774bda   none        swap        defaults    0 0
   ```
5. Now save the file and exit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.
6. Reboot.

Comment: Now I'm stuck in tty1.

Comment: @Steingrim - What else did you do? Apart from the steps I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Besides using vim instead of nano, I followed youre answer step by step

Comment: @Steingrim - Edit your question with the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/default/grub`. Also, did you follow any other solutions?